# Mutual independence of three events

Tags: probability, independence

As I understand it, if three events are mutually independent, then $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)\cdot P(B)\cdot P(C)$. I'd like to know if the converse is also true, that is, if $P(A)\cdot P(B)\cdot P(C) = P(A\cap B\cap C)$, are $A$, $B$, and $C$ mutually independent?  The [question here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/find-a-counterexample-for-a-false-statment-about-independent-events.539834/) seems to suggest that that isn't true, and the last response (see below) supports that conclusion, but I'm wondering if both the question and the response might be flawed.

> Useful example. Whole space has numbers $1$ through $8$, each with probability = $1/8$.
>
> Let $A = B = {1,2,3,4}$
>
> Let $C = {1,5,6,7}$
>
> $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=1/2$
>
> $P(A$ and $B$ and $C)=P({1})=1/8$.
>
> However $A$ and $B$ are obviously not independent. Also $A$ and $C$ are not independent.

I appreciate any light you can shed on the issue.

Comment: The counter example appears valid. Can you be more specific about what isnt clear to you?

Comment: It seems to me that the counter example provides an example of events that are not mutually exclusive rather than ones that are not independent.

Comment: An event can be both not mutually exclusive and not independent. On the other hand, I don't think an event can be both mutually exclusive and independent (although I am not sure about events that almost-surely do not occur). So being mutually exclusive does not prohibit this from being a counter-example. The (pair-wise) not-independent status of the events is easily determined as shown in the answer below.

Comment: To more precise, I'm having trouble with the phrase "A and B are obviously not independent" is that simply b/c it's clear that $P(A)\cdot P(B) \neq P(A\cap B)$? Are A = {1, 2, 3, 4} and B = {3, 4, 5, 6} independent since P(A) $\cdot$ P(B) = .25 and P(A $\cap$ B) also equals .25?

Comment: I've added an answer which might help. Independence can seem confusing without context. Those two events you describe are independent because they satisfy the definition of independent.

Comment: I hope this may be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3157866/351322

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your confusion is that in order for three events $A$, $B$ and $C$ to be mutually independent it is necessary but not sufficient that $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \times P(B) \times P(C)$ (condition 1).

The other condition that must be met is that each pair of events must also be independent [so $A$ and $B$ must be independent, $B$ and $C$ must be independent and $A$ and $C$ must be independent - also known as pairwise independence (condition 2)].

As shown in your example, condition 1 can be met by events that violate condition 2. Events $A$ and $B$ are dependent ($P(A|B) \ne P(A) \times P(B)$ and $P(B|A) \ne P(A) \times P(B)$) and so events $A$, $B$ and $C$ are not mutually independent.

**Mutual Independence of three events** For any three events $A$, $B$ and $C$ to be mutually independent the following two conditions must be met:

1. $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \times P(B) \times P(C)$
2. $A$ and $B$ must be independent, $B$ and $C$ must be independent and $A$ and $C$ must be independent

**Mutual Independence of $n$ events**
Events $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ are mutually independent iff for any sub-collection of $k$ events, $A_{i1}, A_{i2},...,A_{ik}$, it is true that:

$$P(A_{i1} \cap A_{i2} \cap ... \cap A_{ik}) = P(A_{i1}) \times P(A_{i2}) \times ... \times P(A_{ik})$$

Answer (score 2):

This was growing too long for a comment. I'm going to construct a similar (although not equivalent) counterexample using three coins so that independence makes more 'sense'.

To determine if a pair of events are independent, the pair need only satisfy that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.

The state space for three coins could be written as:

$$\{(h,h,h), (h,h,t), (h,t,h), (h,t,t), (t,h,h), (t,h,t), (t,t,h), (t,t,t)\}$$

This can *also* be written as $\{1, 2, \ldots, 8\}$, i.e. by enumerating each outcome.

Consider the following pair of *dependet* events:

1. $A$ the event that the first coin is a head (i.e. state 1, 2, 3 or 4),
2. $B$ the event that the first two coins are heads, or the last two are tails
    (i.e. state 1, 2, 4 or 8).

The dependence is physically obvious; they both rely on the outcome of the first coin flip. We can also see that they don't obey the definition of independence, as

- $P(A \cap B) = P(\text{state 1, 2, or 4}) = 3/8$ and
- $P(A) P(B) = (1/2) \times (1/2) = 1/4$.

Let's consider a third event:

3. $C$ the event that the last two coins are not the same (state 2, 3, 6, 7).

In physical terms, it seems that this event is independent from $A$, because event $C$ doesn't depend on the flip of the first coin, while event $A$ only depends on the first coin. It is easy to show, as well, that they obey the definition of independence.

Meanwhile, event $B$ and $C$ are dependent, in physical terms because they both rely on the outcome of the last two coins; and it is also easy to show that the definition of independence is not satisfied.

Now of course $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(\text{state 2}) = 1/8$, and $P(A) P(B) P(C) = 1/8$, too.

So the question is, still, are they 'mutually independent'? No. As per the definition of independence for multiple events, *we require that each pair of events is independent* - which we have already seen is false.